# Errno 14 HTTPS Error 500 - Internal Server Error while trying to download a package

Tags: centos7, yum, google-artifact-registry

I have a public yum repository in Google Artifact Registry, which contains a yum package. I was trying to install the package into an EC2 server(ultraserve-centos-7.4).
I have created a local yum repository file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` to access my yum repository.

```
[my-repo]
name=my-repo
baseurl=https://LOCATION-yum.pkg.dev/projects/PROJECT/REPOSITORY_NAME
enabled=1
repo_gpgcheck=0
gpgcheck=0
```

And then updated my repository sources with `sudo yum makecache`. The metadata cache gets created successfully.

```
my-repo                                                                                                        | 1.4 kB  00:00:00     
ultra-centos-7.4-base                                                                                          | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
ultra-centos-7.4-extras                                                                                        | 3.3 kB  00:00:00     
ultra-centos-7.4-updates                                                                                       | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
ultra-centos-7.x-newrelic-monitoring                                                                           | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
ultra-centos-7.x-ultrarepo                                                                                     | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
Metadata Cache Created
```

Then, when I try to download and install the package I get:

```
[Errno 14] HTTPS Error 500 - Internal Server Error
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  xxxxxx-0.7.0~SNAPSHOT-xxxxx-1.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

It understands which package/version to download exactly, but fails to download it.
Can anyone help me out with what exactly is going wrong? Or what I'm missing?

Comment: can you verify that the artifact is available in the repository?

Comment: @jediz yes the package is available and visible in the repo